# php/mysql/ajax join in query and accessing resulting variables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, join

I have a query of a mysql database that joins two tables.  In the first table it just pulls records based on an id.  For the second table, there may or may not be matches based on a value in the first table.  I want to get matches if there are any, otherwise, presumably those values of the resulting record set are empty.

The query seems to produce the right number of records.  However, when I try to access values of some variables that should be present, I am not getting anything, either because I may be calling them the wrong name or they are not in recordset somehow.  I am a bit fuzzy on mysql queries so would greatly appreciate any advice..

Table 1 parks

```
id | name | stateid
```

Table 2 parksvisited

```
id | visited | parkid | userid
```

PHP script

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM `parks` p
LEFT JOIN `parksvisited` pv
ON p.id = pv.parkid
WHERE p.stateid = '44'"
```

run query...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
if ($row['visited'] == 1) {
$visited = 1; }  
else {
$visited = 0; }
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadParks(\''.$row['stateid'].'\',\''.$row['p.id'].'\',\''.$visited.'\');">Visited</a>

}
```

Basically, I get stateid but I am not getting p.id or visited.  It could be I am naming them wrong or possibly they are getting left out of results somehow...  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: test the query in phpmyadmin first and see what you get there or else var_dump ( $row)

Comment: I have done that and the id field seems to be there, however, it is not showing up as I've referenced it in html

Comment: is there an alternative to var_dump to see what fields are being outputted..

Comment: You could do `echo '<pre>';print_r(mysql_fetch_array($res));exit;` somewhere. See my answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.id` is probably missing because each of `p.id` and `pv.id` are going to get returned as `id`, not as `p.id` or `pv.id`. Try this instead:

```
SELECT p.id pid,
       p.*,
       pv.id pvid,
       pv.*
FROM `parks` p
LEFT JOIN `parksvisited` pv
ON p.id = pv.parkid
WHERE p.stateid = '44'
```

It also doesn't look like you're selecting anything from `pv` in your original query, just `p`. See if this new query takes care of `visited` as well. And make sure to refer to `pid` as `$row['pid']`, not `$row['p.id']`.

Comment: that sounds right.  row['p.name'] is not returning anything.  Should I add an as to the alias ie p.id as pid

Comment: Not unless you want to. It's going to be `$row['name']`, not `$row['p.name']`. The table names don't come across. Only the column names or aliases you give the column names.

Comment: So the only time you NEED to do an alias is when you're selecting from two tables that share a column name. Otherwise it's optional.